# How to find the answer to following hash table based on open addressing?

Tags: hash, chaining

A hash table has m slots and uses open addressing with linear probing to resolve collisions.The table initially empty.Key k1 is inserted into the table, followed by k2, and then k3. Explain the condition for there to be 4 probes while inserting these keys? what is probability of getting 4 probes?

Comment: This isn't a homework help place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not programming.


Answer (score 0):

**Actually This is not place for your home Work ,next time when you post a Question ,analyse it  please be focus on research type Questions**

However I created few diagrams , hope it will helpful ,

here  whole question and answer with diagrams : [kelums.wordpress.com](http://kelums.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/consider-a-hash-table-with-m-slots-that-uses-open-addressing-with-linear-probing-the-table-is-initially-empty-a-key-k1-is-inserted-into-the-table-followed-bykey-k2-and-then-key-k3-what-is-the-pro/)

1 if 1st 2 keys collide

Diagram_1: www.kelums.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/1.png

2 if 1st 2 keys doesn’t collide  ,1st key 3rd key collide

Diagram_2: www.kelums.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/2.png

3 if 1st 2 keys doesn’t collide  , 2nd  key 3rd key collide :

Diagram_3: www.kelums.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/3.png

RESOURCE : [MIT Handout](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall10/psets/ps2/ps2-solA.pdf)

Since the insertion of each element requires at least one(Its only one on this term) probe, for there to
be 4 probes, there needs to be at least one collision.

If the first two keys collide, we do
not even need to know where the third key hashes to – there is already a collision.
 The
probability that the first two keys collide is **1/m.**

If the first two keys do not collide,
then the third key needs to hash to one of the two slots that the first two keys hash to in
order for there to be a collision. 
The probability of this happening is the product of the
probability that the first two keys do not collide and the probability that the third key
goes into one of the two slots that the first two keys hash to: 
**(m-1)/m *2/m**

The total probability of having at least 4 probes is **1/m + (m-1)/m *2/m**

Comment: @rumesh we analysed it, that one and my answer are different  , if you can go thorough that PDF sensitively you will see changes